# Blocked: In Azure Logic app, how can you add group of checkboxes for each of the languages for a user to choose for caption translation option?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-video-indexer

I have created a logic app, to pull the Video Transcript(VTT) caption file, once the videos have been indexed. I want the user to have the ability to choose which language they would like the captions to be translated in ( For e.g English, Spanish, French, Portuguese etc).

Is there a way to add group of check boxes for each of the languages for the user to choose? I was looking at this :https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index but it looks like the API supports only one language. In my case, I want to present the user with (check boxes) with at least 10 different languages they can choose from.

**Question:** How can we have this implemented for a user to choose from a checkbox of languages? Or can I accept a list of languages as my HTTP request and loop over them in my logic app?

Here is the current workflow of my logic app, where it allows only one language at the moment:

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to pass the list languages through HTTP trigger body (it accepts JSON array). You can generate the request schema by pasting your sample request data (payload) through "Use sample payload to generate schema" link.

Then in the "For each" action you'll iterate through the languages and call the other actions.

[image: something like this]

After you can test your Logic App for example in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Hi Peter, in your example can show how you are passing the list languages through HTTP trigger body" For example if I want to pass in English, French, Spanish how could I pass them. How can I do that?

Comment: You can POST (by using HTTP POST URL) the body with the languages. The "interface" of your Logic App is HTTP trigger it's where you pass your entry parameters.

Comment: Could please give an example of how the POST URL will look like? This is my HTTP POST URL: https://prod-31.westus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/c49cce1b11b54b29be8243afce72e777/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=AMAVjHuXEicuZakpD88iR1VZtrrqV6O3EfFCIxMGDIQ .  Where would I pass the languages?

Comment: sorry didn't mean to ask too many questions :) I am just bit confused and trying to understand.

Comment: You can test the Logic App in Postman by adding JSON body to the POST request. I've add it to the answer.

Comment: but from a user perspective how is this going to work? I mean, is there a way  for a user to choose what language they want the caption to be in? Like maybe a check box with a list of languages for the user to choose?

Comment: No, there's nothing like user interaction in Logic App. It's "just" a workflow. You have to develop your application/client that will enable you to choose the languages outside of Logic App e.g. create a web app that will call that URL.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a way for a user to select a language that they want the caption to be translated in? I thought of creating a check boxes of languages for a user to pick from. Could pleas tell me how I could approach in doing this? Is this something that can be easily done?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is out of scope of the question. As I wrote the Logic App is just a workflow and you need to develop your client application. You should search for such an answer or put another question how to create such a HTML form etc.